# Find and replace first digit with a constant 3 digits with notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++

I have a bunch of numbers like this:

```
0772789675
0756789878
0701789976
0796788765
```

All the way, they're about 1000 in a notepad++ file. I would want to prepend them with 256 in this format

```
256772789675
256756789878
256701789976
256796788765
```

anybody know how to go about this?

Comment: You can do that easily with regex in Notepad++.

Comment: Alternatively, use shift+alt and select down the left column of 0, then over type with 256

Answer (score 3):

#### I would like to replace the leading 0s with 256

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^0`
- Set "Replace with" to `256`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

Before:

```
0772789675
0756789878
0701789976
0796788765
```

After:

```
256772789675
256756789878
256701789976
256796788765
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)